# Formtastic non-model form, integration with external site, override/specify the input ID values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, formtastic

I'm using formtastic to collect information from a form and post dirctly to an external site.

I have no problem generating the form itself.  However, since this is being submitted to an external site, they require that each input field have the specific IDs they specify, eg `email` or `last_name` -- not the closest Formtastic form, eg `_email_input` or `_last_name_input`.

I've looked at the Formtastic v1.2.3 code and I'm 90% sure the answer is "sorry, can't do that." I figured it couldn't hurt to check if I'm missing something.  I would like some way to specify the ID completely, as in:

```
= semantic_form_for('', :url => "https://external_site.com/handler, :method => "post") do |form|
  = form.input :last_name, :id => "last_name"
  [etc]
```

Is this possible?

(I will note that I recognize that another, arguably superior approach would be to create an appropriate controller, sanity check the parameters locally, and dispatch the remote call from within the app only when it's well formed; however, that's not what I'm trying to do at the moment.)

Comment: Sorry, Shreyas -- I only got back to this today, lots of balls in the air.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly i think you need to use semantic_fields_for for non-model forms. Next, to pass ids to each field, you can use the input_html options to specify them. for eg

```
form.input :email, :input_html => {:name => 'email', :id => 'email' }
```

Comment: I accepted this answer, but the suggestion to use semantic_fields_for didn't work correctly (added numeric indexes before each input).  However, it was definitely :input_html for which I was hunting fruitlessly.  Thanks, and sorry for the delay getting back to you.